como puedo resolver error en holt-winters
A que se debe este error en RStudio  con Holt-winters: optimization difficulties: ERROR: ABNORMAL_TERMINATION_IN_LNSRCH
Solo tengo una variable con 30 datos.
Como lo puedo resolver si la serie tiene tendencia
mod1=HoltWinters(m15045_ts,gamma = FALSE)

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
